# How to keep sequential order of events when adding color to barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I'm trying to create a plot that describes the actions of my students over time.  I am having trouble getting the correct order of events to come up when I add color.  For example, when I use the following code, I get the correct order of events, but not color:

```
ggplot(data=activity_timeline, aes(x=" ", y = Total.Time))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black")+
  facet_grid(facets=Name~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "green"),
                    name= "The student was doing:",
                    labels = c("Analysis", "Implementation", "None", "Organizing", "Planning", "Research", "Verification"))+
  ggtitle("                                           Time Spent on Problem Solving Activities")+
  labs(y = "Time in seconds", x = " ")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12))
```

Right order, no color

[image: Right order, no color]

When I add the option for color (line 2), the graph groups all of the items together that have the same Action.  The code I am using for that is:

```
ggplot(data=activity_timeline, aes(x=" ", y = Total.Time))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", aes(fill=Action))+
  facet_grid(facets=Name~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "purple", "orange", "green"),
                    name= "The student was doing:",
                    labels = c("Analysis", "Implementation", "None", "Organizing", "Planning", "Research", "Verification"))+
  ggtitle("                                           Time Spent on Problem Solving Activities")+
  labs(y = "Time in seconds", x = " ")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=12),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_text(size=12))
```

Wrong order, with color

[image: Wrong order, with color]

I am completely new to ggplot and doing this off of code that I've found online.  I have attempted to use the "timeline" function and I can't figure out how to get that to work with my data.  If anyone has any suggestions about how to fix this code, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to order the stacked bars in a specific sequence, you can create an additional column in your dataset indicating that sequence. Otherwise I believe geom_bar orders the bars by their filled colours by default.

Here's a sample dataset for illustration:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(t = rexp(100, rate = 0.1),
                 student = c(rep("s1", 50), rep("s2", 50)),
                 activity = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 100, replace = T),
                 seq = c(seq(1, 50, 1), seq(1, 50, 1)))

# without group parameter
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = t, fill = activity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  facet_grid(student~.) +
  labs(y="time", x = "") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot without group parameter]

```
# with group parameter
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = t, fill = activity, group = seq)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  facet_grid(student~.) +
  labs(y="time", x = "") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot with group parameter]